# Posting form with AngularJS returns 405 code, after publishing website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, methods, http-status-code-405

I'm having an issue when I post data from a form to server I receive:

```
angular.js:14642 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<html>\n<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\n<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>\n</body>\n</html>","status":405,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/messages","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

Everything works normal on localhost, but after publishing i receive this error on post. My website is published on Github pages and the domain is namecheap.

Here is my route code:

```
module.exports = (function() {
'use strict';
var router = require('express').Router();
var Message = require('./angular/models/messageModel');

router.post('/messages', function(req,res,next){
    var message = new Message();                                    
    message.name = req.body.name;
    message.email = req.body.email;
    message.subject = req.body.subject;
    message.message = req.body.message;

    if(req.body.name == null || req.body.name == "" || req.body.email == null || req.body.email == "" || req.body.subject == null || req.body.subject == "" || req.body.message == null || req.body.message == ""){
    res.json({success: false, message: "Please fill up the required fields!" });}
    if(req.body.message.length<8){
            res.json({success: false, message: "Your message is too short!"});

    } else {
        message.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            } else { 
                res.json({success: true, message: "Message sent!"}); 
                }
        });
    }

});

return router;
})();
```

And here is my request:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/messages',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            data: app.contactData
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have added response headers, but nothing changed

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.stundji.info');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT,');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'application/json');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is resolved.

The problem was coming from GitHub Pages. I switched to Heroku and everything went back to normal. My advice to everyone is not to host their websites on GitHub Pages, seems like it has a restriction on some requests.